# Comparing macro parameters in gnu asm (gas)

Tags: arm, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to create macros for arm assembly (using GNU tools).

```
.macro FUNCTION     name, attrs
    .ifc    \attrs\(),"global"
        .global         \name
    .endif

    // other stuff
.endm
```

So macros `FUNCTION myFunc, global` can be evaluated with `.global` attribute.
However, the marcro does not handle this attribute compare. Simply stated `.if` is never evaluated?

Is there a way to compare such string-like macro parameters?

Comment: yeap, i'm talking about normal asm, not 'in-line' one. BTW **global** without any type of quotes works. `.ifc \attrs, global ... .endif`. @artless noise, if you put it as answer I'll mark it as correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gas uses [single quotes](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/If.html#If) to denote strings and not double quotes.

> .ifc string1,string2
>
> Assembles the following section of code if the two strings are the same. The strings may be **optionally quoted with single quotes**. If they are not quoted, the first string stops at the first comma, and the second string stops at the end of the line. **Strings which contain whitespace should be quoted**. The string comparison is case sensitive.

If there is no spaces or other parsing issue, as with **global**, you can just use the name as is without any quoting.  So an acceptable solutions is,

```
.macro FUNCTION     name, attrs
    .ifc    \attrs\(),global
        .global         \name
    .endif

    // other stuff
.endm
```